# Bash. CentOS 7. Cron

Tags: bash, centos

Нужно написать скрипт которая каждый час создаст файл в каталоге /tmp и удалит его.
Поискал в интернете. Узнал что нужно воспользоватся cron.Есть cron.hourly которая выполняет какое-то действие каждые 60 минут.
Подскажите пример такого скрипта работающий каждые 60мин.

Comment: А в чём смысл этой манипуляции? И в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: ну это я пытаюсь изучить Bash. А по поводу вопроса согласен с вами я не написал в чем вопрос но уже исправил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

создать файл:

```
$ touch /путь/к/файлу
```

удалить файл:

```
$ rm /путь/к/файлу
```

выполнить две команды последовательно:

```
$ команда1; команда2
```

один из вариантов создания ежечасно выполняемого (например, интерпретатором *bash*) cron-задания, в случае, если программа *crond* настроена выполнять каждый час скрипты из каталога `/etc/cron.hourly`:

1. создайте файл `/etc/cron.hourly/произвольное-имя` следующего содержания:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   команда1; команда2
   ```
2. установите биты исполнимости для этого файла:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/произвольное-имя
   ```

Comment: *выполнить две команды **последовательно**: $ команда1; команда2* -- зависит от комманд, правильнее `wait` использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если в кроне, тогда пишем `crontab -e` и в нем строка:

```
* */1 * * * touch /tmp/filename && rm -f /tmp/filename
```